# Can you call double-click VBA Userform subs from a module?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have several userforms which contain identical text-boxes. I have double-click subs within the userforms for simple copy and paste: where the user just has to select a cell to copy and then double click in the appropriate text-box to paste:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  Me.txtSearch = Selection
End Sub
```

At the moment I have about 6 of these copied across 5 different userforms. To avoid pointless duplication, is it possible to place these subs in a module or just a single userform where the subs are public?

Thanks

Comment: You can certainly put the code into a normal module, passing a Control as the argument, but I'm not sure you'll see a lot of benefit for 6 instances of the code.

Comment: Each textbox still needs the Double click event script. But in that script, it can pass itself as an argument to a generalized sub. This could be useful if the sub was long/complicated and you didn't want to repeat it multiple times, but if its just one line... there's not much benefit.

Comment: If you realy want to spend a day saving 5 time 3 minutes, study "Reflection in VBA". You will be able to create a workbook that adds a textbox and a call back routine to all its sheets when it is opened. _(It is however possible, your organization does not allow you to use reflection)_

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to place all these double-click subs in a single place, to minimise editing in the future. How would I place a double-click sub in to a normal module? I’ve tried a few different ways, but to no avail. I’m fairly new to VBA.

Comment: You could also create a class. But that amounts to the same thing that Toddleson has already written. Little benefit, unless you plan many more text fields.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's not possible to put a double-click textbox sub in a normal module (unless you use advanced VBA and time consuming methods), but if you have a lot of code running in a double-click sub, then you can call an open sub from a module. Is that correct?